# scala project does not work in intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I am getting the following error log when setting up a scala project in intellij:

```
Error:Error while importing SBT project:<br/>...<br/><pre>[error]   at 
sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1(MainLoop.scala:107)
[error]     at sbt.io.Using.apply(Using.scala:22)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:101)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:57)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:42)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:34)
[error]     at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:113)
[error]     at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:76)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:128)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35) 
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:41)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:17)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
[error] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jetbrains.sbt.CreateTasks$
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
[info] shutting down server</pre><br/>See complete log in <a href="file:/home/moritz/.IdeaIC2017.2/system/log/sbt.last.log">file:/home/xxxx/.IdeaIC2017.2/system/log/sbt.last.log</a>
```

My build.sbt looks as follows:

```
name := "someProjectName"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.4"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.1" % "test"
```

Please also note that my "old" projects still work, i.e. this issue occurcs only when doing a new project. Further, I noticed that when I click on SBT projects on the very right, it opens an empty window "SBT projects", for my other projects that window is non-empty.

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Many thanks
c

Comment: If the given answers don't help, please paste/link to the sbt.last.log

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have been experiencing this problem myself, and solved it by upgrading to intellij version: 2017.3.2 build #IU-173.4127.27.

I think this may have to do with sbt 1.X series no longer being available on the typesafe bintray repository, as I was also having a problem performing some Docker builds.

Comment: The reason is a bug in earlier versions of the IntelliJ Scala plugin that makes it incompatible with sbt 1.1 due to how it calculates binary version numbers.

Answer (score 12):

In case you don't want the hassle of upgrading Intellij, you can  downgrade the sbt version in `sbt.properties` file from 1.1.0 (the project default) to, for instance, 1.0.3.

Comment: I had to download an older sbt version (0.13.18) and modify the sbt.properties with it, which is inside the myapp/project folder.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, so I could not create any Scala class in my project. Found a workaround, by creating a scala module in my project:

1. Select your project folder, go to File menu, File->New->Module.
2. In module select Scala and setup your Scala SDK there.
3. Then you can create scala classes in this module.

Answer (score 1):

downgrade the sbt version in sbt.properties and remove target folder from project and project/project